# Collections.synchronizedList and synchronized

Tags: java, collections, synchronization

```
List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
synchronized (list) {
    list.add("message");
}
```

Is the block "synchronized (list){} " really need here ?

Answer (score 100):

You don't need to synchronize as you put in your example.  HOWEVER, very important, you need to synchronize around the list when you iterate it (as noted in the Javadoc):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
> ...
> synchronized(list) {
>     Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>         foo(i.next());   
> }
> ```

Comment: Link to the above statement: [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))

Comment: A common use case with a synchronised collection like this is to add to the list in multiple threads, but to iterate it only at the end when all tasks have complete.
In this case, I don't see any reason to synchronise around the iteration, since it's being done from a single thread.

Comment: As long as you know the list is not being updated while you're iterating, you don't need to synchronize it.  I don't know if I would characterize that use case as "common", though. (I've seen ConcurrentModificationException quite a number of times.)  In the use case you mention, what's preventing a thread from adding to the list again while the other thread is iterating?  And how does the iterating thread "know" when the other threads are done updating the list?

Comment: Similarly for Collections.synchornizedMap, need to use synchronized keyword for iteration or manipulation of Map

Comment: If the list is not synchronized, won't there anyways be a concurrent modification exception?

Answer (score 29):

It depends on the exact contents of the `synchronized` block:

1. If the block performs a single, atomic operation on the list (as in your example), the `synchronized` is superfluous.
2. If the block performs multiple operations on the list -- **and needs to maintain the lock for the duration of the compound operation** -- then the `synchronized` is **not** superfluous. One common example of this is iterating over the list.

Answer (score 22):

The underlying code for Collections.synchronizedList add method is:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    synchronized (mutex) {list.add(index, element);}
}
```

So in your example it is not needed to add synchronisation.

Comment: And what would be an example of a mutex that it uses?

Comment: The mutex is the collection itself (this) as documented in the javadoc.

Answer (score 17):

Also Important to note that any methods that use Iterators for example Collections.sort() will also need to be encapsulated inside a synchronized block.

Comment: from Java 8, the sort method has been added to the List interface and this method already synchronizes on the mutex. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-

Answer (score 7):

Read this [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

It says "It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it"

Comment: This doc sounds rather like a dogma than the explanation. That's why I found this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Like what has been mentioned by others, the synchronized collections are **thread-safe**, but the compound actions to these collections are not guaranteed to be thread-safe by default.

According to JCIP, the common compound actions can be

- iteration
- navigation
- put-if-absent
- check-then-act

The OP's synchronized code block isn't a compound action, so no difference whether add it or not.

Let's take the example from JCIP and modify it a little to clarify why it's necessary to guard the compound actions with lock.

There are two methods that operate on same collection `list` that wrapped by `Collections.synchronizedList`

```
public Object getLast(List<String> list){
    int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
    return list.get(lastIndex);
}

public void deleteLast(List<String> list){
    int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
    list.remove(lastIndex);
}
```

If methods `getLast` and `deleteLast` are called at the same time by two different threads, below interleaves may happen and `getLast` will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Assume current `lastIndex` is 10.

Thread A (deleteLast) --> remove
Thread B (getLast)    --------------------> get

The Thread A `remove` the element before the `get` operation in Thread B. Thus, the Thread B still use 10 as the `lastIndex` to call `list.get` method, it will lead to concurrent problem.