# why synchronize a synchronized list?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

If I create such a list:

```
List<MyObj> myobjs = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<MyObj>());
```

the associated documentation claims that this returned list needs to be synchronized in order to iterate over the elements. Yet, I can synchronize a regular List and protect it with a synchronized block. So, why do I need a "synchronizedList"?

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified
>   list. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all
>   access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.
>
> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:

```
  List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
      ...
  synchronized (list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic
>   behavior. The returned list will be serializable if the specified list
>   is serializable.
>
> Parameters: list the list to be "wrapped" in a synchronized list.
>   Returns: a synchronized view of the specified list.

Comment: It has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468187/collections-synchronizedlist-and-synchronized. Simple operations are guaranteed to be thread safe, but iterating is not a simple opration.

Comment: I agree that the questions are similar, but not exact duplicates. i.e. I asked what is the purpose of the SynchronizedList if you also need to synchronize, and romsky asked what is the purpose of synchronize when using SynchronizedList.

Comment: Because it can only be synchronized for simple operations... How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `synchronizedList` is a convenience wrapper that allows you to avoid manual synchronization in most cases, but not when iterating over it.

With a normal unsynchronized list, you would need to always manually synchronize if it is used by multiple threads, thus it can be handy to use `synchronizedList`.

A case where a `synchronizedList` are necessary might be if you pass a list to some third-party code that does not synchronize on the list, but you still need synchronization. However, this is quite error-prone as you would rely on the fact that the third-party code does not iterate over the list or use other non-atomic operations, thus it would be best to avoid this altogether if possible (for example, by copying the list).

Comment: Thanks... From romski's post, "Also Important to note that any methods that use Iterators for example Collections.sort() will also need to be encapsulated inside a synchronized block."